# Eiminate dulicated values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to eliminate some duplicated values of my DataFrame with no success, using pandas. 
My DataFrame has two columns, but I only need to work with one of theme, but i can't achieve what I need.

[image]

The important column is the second. I need to eliminate the values that appear more than one time.

if you have any questions, feel free to ask them!

Edit: I'm adding what i have tried with no success

```
df = pd.read_csv(str(cancion.csv))
saved_column = df.ix[:,0]
saved_column.drop_duplicates()
print saved_column
```

The original DataFrame had two columns, but I only need the first one, so I have selected only that, as shown in the image. So, in the remaining column, I need to eliminate the duplicated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   col1
0    22
1    33
2    22
3    36
4    77
5    36
```

Result:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
   col1
0    22
1    33
3    36
4    77
```

If you have the Single column then you may also try like Below:

```
>>> df.col1.drop_duplicates()
0    22
1    33
3    36
4    77
```

Comment: This was just the answer. I was trying that but not in the correct place. thanks!